# Perl: Copying an array from a hash of hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Given a HoHoA

```
my %FIELDS = (
    LA => {
      NAME => [1],
      ADDRESS => [2,3,4,5],
      TYPE => [6],
      LICENCE => [0],
      ACTIVE => [],
    },
...
);
```

I'm trying to make a copy of a particular array

```
my @ADDRESS_FIELDS = @{$FIELDS{$STATE}->{ADDRESS} };
```

Since everything inside %FIELDS is by reference the arrow de-references the inner hash and the @{} de-references the array. (I understand that the arrow isn't strictly necessary)

```
print $ADDRESS_FIELDS[3]."\n";
print @ADDRESS_FIELDS."\n";
```

gives

```
5
4
```

The first print behaves as expected but the second one is giving me the scalar value of, I assume, the referenced array instead of a new copy. Where am I going astray?

Comment: What do you mean by "instead of a new copy"? The `4` is indeed just the array evaluated in scalar context, which yields the number of elements. Maybe you were looking for `print "@ADDRESS_FIELDS\n"`?

Comment: *Headdesk*

Sometimes we overlook the little things. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concatenation operator forces scalar context on its operands. Use a comma instead:

```
print @array, "\n";
```

Note that the elements are separated by `$,`, which is empty by default.

Or, to separate the array elements by `$"` (space by default) in the output, use

```
print "@array\n";
```

Or, join them yourself:

```
print join(' ', @array), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat my.pl 
#!/bin/perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %FIELDS = (
    LA => {
        NAME => [1],
        ADDRESS => [2,3,4,5],
        TYPE => [6],
        LICENCE => [0],
        ACTIVE => []
    },
);

my @addy = @{$FIELDS{LA}->{ADDRESS}};
foreach my $i(@addy){
    print "i=$i\n";
}
perl my.pl
i=2
i=3
i=4
i=5
```

Comment: you forgot to reference LA

Answer (score 0):

```
print @ADDRESS_FIELDS."\n";
```

Evaluates your array in a scalar context and returns the number of elements (which in your case is 4).

```
print join(', ', @ADDRESS_FIELDS)."\n";
```

is what you want i guess.

HTH